# Display XSLT report inside mail body with Email-ext plugin in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, testng, email-ext

Is it possible to display XSLT report inside mail body using Email-ext plugin in Jenkins.

i have configured the Content Type to HTML and placed the following to the body:

```
$DEFAULT_CONTENT
${FILE,path="target/site/reportyng-xslt/index.html"}
```

When email is send i get nothing and on the console output, there's no error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FILE` token *"Includes the content of a specified file (path) relative to the workspace root."* not relative to the Maven project's base dir.

I experienced the following with Jenkins v1.595 and Email Ext. Plugin v2.39:

- `${FILE,path="file_directly_in_job's_workspace"}` → prints content of file in message
- `${FILE,path="not_existing_file"}` → prints
  *"ERROR: File 'not_existing_file' does not exist"* in message
- `${FILE,path="path/with/sub/dirs/to/existing_file"}` → prints content of file in message
- `${FILE,path="XML_file_including_tags_unknown_to_HTML.xml"}` → seems to print nothing in an e-mail client that renders HTML in messages, like Outlook. Content can be seen in the messages' source, however.

Comment: ${FILE,path="target/site/reportyng-xslt/index.html"}, the path is relative to the workspace root, not the maven project. Not really sure where am going wrong